# "ValueError: cannot allocate more than 256 colors" when using ImageDraw.Draw()

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the following code:

```py
def draw():
    img = Image.open(image)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("Poppins-Thin.ttf", 20)
    watermark_text = "some text"
    draw.text((0, img.height - 25), watermark_text, (211, 211, 211), font=font)
    return img
```

It works with some images, but some throw a `ValueError: cannot allocate more than 256 colors` error. Manipulating a failing image works without the `draw` function (I am resizing and compressing it).

How can I have it work for all supported images?

[Working image example.](https://mega.nz/file/seY2lYKI#F1_ZFf36AmUNsCl_o875M7_4B5Vdfp1P-LCTCHCNCj8)

[Failing image example.](https://mega.nz/file/hD4CzBpJ#2hlseJ-uHLFh2GtlfY0WAMO8kdTYWn-TN36fkDPVbOE)

Comment: some files may not have RGB colors but they may use indexed-colors (which may use only 256 indexes) and you may have to convert to RGB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This image use indexed-colors (it keeps RGB colors on list and every pixel has only index to this color) and it may use only 256 indexes.
This way file is smaller, it uses less memory RAM and less space on disk, and web page can load it faster - so users don't resign to visit page (and server sends less bytes so it costs less)

You have to convert to `RGB` (or `RGBA` if you whan to keep transparent background)

```
img = img.convert('RGBA')
```

Eventually you can use index to some color (ie. `221`) instead of tuple `(R,G,B)` in

```
draw.text((0, img.height - 25), watermark_text, 211)
```

but it makes problem to recognize what color it will give on image.

---

You can detect type of pallete (mode) with

```
print(img.mode)
```

and here [explanations](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)